# Telling return type of function with multiple possibilities

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

how could TS know the return type of functions with multiple return type like:

```
type VariantA = Variant & {
    a: number,
    b: string,
    c: string[]
} 

type VariantB = Variant & {
    e: number,
    f: string,
    g: string[]
}

const CreateObject = (type: 'variantA' | 'variantB') => {
    if (type === 'variantA') {
        return { a: 5, b: 'hello', c: ['a', 'b'] } as VariantA
    } else {
        return { e: 5, f: 'hello', g: ['a', 'b'] } as VariantB
    }
}
```

Here its would be cool if the editor could tell if I pass 'variantA' as type, then the return type is VariantA else VariantB. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ah I solved it (but there are might better alternatives?)

So I just created a few overloads:

```
function CreateObject(type: 'typeA' | 'typeB'): VariantA
function CreateObject(type: 'typeA' | 'typeB'): VariantB
function CreateObject(type: 'typeA' | 'typeB'): VariantA | VariantB {
    if (type === 'typeA') {
        return { a: 1, b: '2', c: ['3', '4'] } as VariantA
    } else {
        return { e: 1, f: '2', g: ['3', '4'] } as VariantB
    }
}
```

Now TS gonna choose the best option (hopefully lol)

Comment: Very close, make the first signature `(type: 'typeA'): VariantA` and the second `(type: 'typeB'): VariantB` and now calls will get the return type `VariantA` or `VariantB` depending what the argument is.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two interfaces and the use the Union type a return type.

```
interface VariantA{
  a: number,
  b: string,
  c: string[]
}

interface VariantB{
  e: number,
  f: string,
  g: string[]
}

type Variants = VariantA | VariantB;

const createObject = (type: string): Variants => {
  if (type === 'variantA') {
      return { a: 5, b: 'hello im variant A', c: ['a', 'b'] }
  } else {
      return { e: 5, f: 'hello im variant B', g: ['a', 'b'] }
  }
};

const objectA = createObject('variantA');
const objectB = createObject('variantB');
console.log(objectA);
console.log(objectB);
```

Comment: But in that case won't TS give objectA the typeof: VariantA | VariantB, instead of being specific about it and giving it VariantA as the return type?

Comment: It will, that's why @aaron-beall's comment fix to your answer is the right solution.